# problem in sqlite database ,help!

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i have a problem in sqlite database connected with iphone sdk for eg. when i put values in lets say upto 5 primary key.but when i delete them all and put new values ,then the integer primary key start from 6 and not from 1 or 0?what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using identity (also called autoincrement) field for the key. It's value is set to   0 when you create the table and increments every time you insert a row. It never comes back though.